# How to configure VSCode with Rust for binary execution?

Tags: rust, vscode-tasks

Assuming that I'm editing the `lession_1/src/main.rs` file, I want to `Ctrl+F5` (or just `F5`) keyboard shortcut and have the following command executed (as if I was running it from `lession_1` directory):

```bash
cargo run
```

#### My project structure

```
├── lesson_1
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── lesson_2
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── lesson_3
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── .pre-commit-config.yaml
├── .pre-commit-hooks.yaml
├── README.md
├── .secrets.baseline
└── Untitled.ipynb
```

#### What I tried

I followed up [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/rust-with-visual-studio-code-46404befed8#e9b9), however, I do get an error:

```
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/home/me/projects/my_rust_project` or any parent directory
```

#### My config

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "/usr/bin/cargo",
            "args": ["run", "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
     "label": "cargo build",
     "type": "shell",
     "command": "cargo build",
     "args": [],
     "group": {
       "kind": "build",
       "isDefault": true
     }
    },
    {
        "label": "cargo run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "cargo",
        "args": [
          "run"
          // "--release",
          // "--",
          // "arg1"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
       }]
  }
```

Comment: I don't know how to connect it in VSCode but you can specify the `Cargo.toml` to use using [`--manifest-path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-locate-project.html?highlight=manifest-path#manifest-options)

Comment: Also tried that, but it didn't work either. However, I'm not sure if I did it right, so given the files that I have (see the `My config` section), what would be your advice?

Comment: Change `cwd` from `"${workspaceFolder}"` to `"${fileDirname}"`.  See VSCode's [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the structure of your project, you have several Cargo package in your workspace.

In your launch.json, `cwd` is set to the workspace folder and Cargo doesn't know which package to run.

Replace `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` by `"cwd": "${relativeFileDirname}"` and Cargo will be run from the folder containing the Rust file you are currently editing, and should easily find the associated Cargo.toml.

For the tasks.json, the same solution can apply, but it means you are only building the Cargo package you are currently editing and not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Answer suggested by @eggyal

Changing the `.vscode/tasks.json` as follows does the job:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "/usr/bin/cargo",
            "args": ["run", "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>"],
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The key is changing the `cwd` from `"${workspaceFolder}"` to `"${fileDirname}"`.

As suggested, see VSCode's [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) for more information.